# Access conflict in ntdll.dll is caused in VS2015 Release Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

When I run the program in VS2015 Release Mode, It breaked as follows:

> 0x000000007743EF57 (ntdll.dll) in (located in GPURenderingApp.exe) caused by the exception: 0xC0000005: write location 0x0000000000000000 access conflict.

But I can run the same program in VS2015 Debug Mode, and in VS2010 Debug and Release Mode, why?

Comment: Your program has a bug -- you're trying to write to address 0.   That is what that error is telling you.

Comment: Your program has a bug, and the VS2015 optimizer has exposed it.  Debug mode doesn't expose it, and VS2010 wasn't as aggressive at optimization.  You will have to step through in the debugger, possibly in assembly mode

Comment: I debug my program in Release Mode, and it got an error in the file e:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0.
inline void _Deallocate(void * _Ptr, size_t _Count, size_t _Sz)
 {  ...  ::operator delete(_Ptr);  }
It got an error on the sentence  ::operator delete(_Ptr)

Comment: Then, somewhere, where you delete a pointer to memory, you're doing something wrong. Use the Call Stack to figure out how you ended up at _Deallocate.